# I want to make an eval command in discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to use this to create an eval command:

````js
const testcode = "hello";


    if (command === "run" || command === "eval") {
      if (message.author.id !== "744752301033521233" && message.author.id !== "716343156513439845")
      return message.channel.send({embed: {
        title: "✍️RUN",
        description: "❌You're not bot owner"
      }});
    try {
      const code = args.join(" ");
      let evaled = eval(code);

      if (typeof evaled !== "string") {
        //console.log(evaled);
        evaled = await require("util").inspect(evaled);
        //console.log(evaled);
      message.channel.send(`\`\`\`xl\n${evaled}\`\`\``);
      } else {
        message.channel.send(`\`\`\`xl\n${evaled}\`\`\``);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      message.channel.send({
        embed: {
          title: "✍️RUN",
          description: "Error:\n```xl\n" + err + "```",
          color: 961818,
          timestamp: new Date(),
          footer: {
            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
          }
        }
      });
    } 
    }
````

This code works correctly for me. (For example, `!run testcode.length` will return 5)
but, this code returns an error if it returns more than 4096 characters.
So I used the split option:

````js
const testcode = "hello";


    if (command === "run" || command === "eval") {
      if (message.author.id !== "744752301033521233" && message.author.id !== "716343156513439845")
      return message.channel.send({embed: {
        title: "✍️RUN",
        description: "❌You're not bot owner"
      }});
    try {
      const code = args.join(" ");
      let evaled = eval(code);

      if (typeof evaled !== "string") {
        //console.log(evaled);
        evaled = await require("util").inspect(evaled);
        //console.log(evaled);
      message.channel.send(`\`\`\`xl\n${evaled}\`\`\``, { split: true });
      } else {
        message.channel.send(`\`\`\`xl\n${evaled}\`\`\``, { split: true });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      message.channel.send({
        embed: {
          title: "✍️RUN",
          description: "Error:\n```xl\n" + err + "```",
          color: 961818,
          timestamp: new Date(),
          footer: {
            icon_url: client.user.avatarURL
          }
        }
      });
    } 
    }
````

But, when I run `!run testcode.length` with this code, I get a `cannot send an empty message` error on the console. How can I fix this bug?

Comment: Never, ever, ever, ever, EVER use `eval` with user input! If you plan to permit others to use this command, then they can run malicious code on your `eval` which can crash your computer or give you a virus. (unlikely, but it is possible). https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-eval. If you want to use eval to run javascript code (such as a bot for showing the output of a piece of code), use something like safe-eval: https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-eval

Comment: @megargayu This code can only be executed by bot owners

Comment: That's an even worse prospect - unless bot owners are hosting their own versions of this script. If you are making a server to host this bot and then giving it to "bot owners", then they can run malicious code on your server and infect it with a virus or crash it completely. On the other hand, if you trust these people and they are self-hosting (they will only harm themselves), then you should *still* use `safe-eval`, as everyone can make mistakes, and someone might accidentally make an infinite loop that crashes the server.